# PHP Fatal error: Class 'InvalidArgumentException' not found in <file> on line X?

Tags: php, logging, apache2

I see this line in my `php.log`:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyNamespace\InvalidArgumentException' not found in <file> on line X
```

Line X contains this:

```
throw new InvalidArgumentException("Error");
```

It happens on the page reload.  First, I put some values into a form, click submit and my page loads.  I click *Refresh Page* (using my browser functions) to reload the page and this is where I get the error.

Maybe when I refresh the page, a different codepath is executed.  But still I deem this to be a native PHP class that should always work, but in my case it throws the error.

I am using PHP, Apache2 on Windows, originally installed via Zend Studio IDE suite.

The [class description](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php) itself does not offer me any hints.  Why does it throw the error and how do I fix it?

*UPDATE**

My code is:

```
if (!isset($modelNumber)) //$modelNumber is NULL when I refresh
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Error");
```

So it is whenever I hit this class I get this error.  When I remove `isset` line and just throw the class directly, it always gives me the error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are using a namespace for the class that the exception is being thrown from. Because of this, PHP is looking for a class called "InvalidArgumentException" *within* that namespace. However, the InvalidArgumentException exists in the Global Namespace. Therefore, in order to access it, simply prepend a backslash before the exception:

```
throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Error");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a backslash before.

```
throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Error");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

`use http\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;`

Comment: Why should he do that?